# Why are digital certificates safe?

Tags: digital-certificate

I’ve read some basics of how digital certificate works, but I don’t understand why it’s safe.

I know a DC contains company name, public key, unique ID, expiration date and it has digital signature. Also, a user can verify it by browser which has a list of root CAs and Intermediate CAs. In addition, those CAs are trusted.

But, still, I don’t understand why this will make sure the message I received from the website is from the authentic website. Say the website x has certificate DCx, and I obtained DCx (although I can’t get the private key). When another user sends request to x, somehow I’m on the route and I intercept this request. I show DCx to the user, he will verify it and it should seem authentic because it has all the valid information. Then I will be able to phish him. Please let me know what I’m missing or wrong.

Maybe the main problem is that I don't fully understand how digital certificate is verified. There are articles talk about how digital certificate is issued and what it contains, but I didn't find any information about how exactly digital certificate is verified when you are opening a website and sending requests.

PS: This question is different than [How does public key encryption work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977473/how-does-public-key-encryption-w) in that the other question only discuss public key, however public key is one component of digital certificate; it contains a lot more.

Comment: When you say "somehow I’m on the route", do you mean you'd be intercepting the transmission (i.e. a man-in-the-middle attack)? This is not possible because, by virtue of how asymmetric encryption works, you cannot decrypt the conversation. The only way you could do that is to obtain the server's private key (aside from the difficulty of intercepting the stream in the first place, of course).

Comment: The actual mathematics of PPK is hard, and most folks only have a passing knowledge of how they work. The one I (vaguely) know about is to do with the factorising of prime numbers. Have you seen [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does public key encryption work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977473/how-does-public-key-encryption-work)

Comment: As an aside, you might want to look into Perfect Forward Secrecy too. This is an extra level of encryption that prevents old recorded ciphertext from being decoded, even if the private key is exposed, as the extra encryption's key is thrown away at the time of use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do digital certificates work when used for securing websites (using SSL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788808/how-do-digital-certificates-work-when-used-for-securing-websites-using-ssl)